# Speaker diarization or Speaker Identification in Android Apps

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I am trying to create an application that recognizes a user and replies to him based on his input . I am not bale to find any SDK or API library that does so.

Please let me know any one that i can start with. I tries nuance SDK, google voice ect.